# optimal way to parse & update nested json

Tags: java, json

I've requirement to parse and update some of the field values in nested json as below

What is the best way to do with Java ?

I googled but didn't find any simple & effective way to do the same

I did refer to question [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java), but answers given there are quite abstract & also doesn't explain how to update particular value against nested key

```
[   {
    "applicationId": "email-id-1202",
    "extRefNumber": "SALARY_STATEMENT-ref-number2018-04-06T17:32:01.852",
    "bankName": "SALARY_STATEMENT",
    "applicants": [
      {
        "personId": "1",
        "documents": [
          {
            "fileId": "2",
            "documentId": "2",
            "type": "TAX_DOCUMENTS"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "data": {
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "branchCode": "branch-code"
    }  ]
```

Comment: Parse the Json using Google Gson or Jackson libraries, make your modification, re-serialize into Json. That's probably the safest way.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul can you please point me to an working example ?

Comment: there are tons of library for json usage in java. just pick one of them and start cracking

Comment: There will be many examples in the documentation of the above mentioned libraries, both of which are open source.

Comment: **com.jayway.jsonpath** might work for you. With simple lines like `DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(Obj.toString());
   doc.set("[0].applicants[0].documents[0].fileId", 3);
    newObj = new JSONArray(doc.jsonString());` you should be able to update  `fileId`. But beware it has two known issues e.g https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272, & issues/375. Using old version like 0.8.1 might work around that.